# SPF - Multiple servers

Tags: spf

I am trying to create a SPF record and wanted some advice.

We have 3 servers, s1.example.com s2.example.com s3.example.com

So far I have constructed this:
"v=spf1 include:s1.example.com include:s2.example.com include:s3.example.com include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all

Should I be using include: or a: for the 3 servers?

Could I just go include:example.com to get all 3?

I am comfortable with the amazon/google as that is what they provided me with

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

v=spf1 a:s1.example.com a:s2.example.com a:s3.example.com include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all